# Asciidoctor Slides without Ruby (but with jRuby)

Tags: reveal.js, asciidoctor, deck.js

I know that there are asciidoctor backends for reveal.js and deck.js but it seems that both are only available as ruby gems and not .jar packages.

While I know how to use the Gems from within a java build, I would like to use these backends without a reference to the ruby gem repository.

So are there already .jar packages available for those backends?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [gradle](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-examples/tree/master/asciidoc-to-revealjs-example) or [maven](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-examples/tree/master/asciidoc-to-revealjs-example) to generate your slide-deck. 
A third option might be to use [asciidocctorj](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj). At least the first two options are easy to use.